# Cant get the site title/header to sit on top of the rest of the content on the page

Tags: css, wordpress, z-index

I am trying to figure out how to make the site title (logo) in the navigation sit on top of everything and hang below the navigation bar - so half of the logo would be in the navigation bar and the other half would hang below. I tried using z-index in a couple spots but it didnt do anything. There is also a shrink feature that I have to get past too. When you scroll down, the navigation bar shrinks and I want the logo to still hang below the nav bar.

Here is the link: http://www.mrsteamers.com/

```
.header-image .site-title > a {
float: left;
min-height: 80px;
width: 100%;
}
.site-header {
background-color: #13afdf;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
z-index: 999;
}

.site-header .wrap {
min-height: 160px;
}

.bumper {
min-height: 160px;

}

.site-header .wrap {
padding: 40px;
max-width: 100%;
}

.site-header.shrink .wrap {
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
min-height: 60px;
padding: 0 40px;
}

.shrink .site-title {
font-size: 36px;
padding-top: 10px;
}

.header-image .shrink .site-title {
padding: 0;
}

.header-image .shrink .site-title > a {
min-height: 60px;
}

.shrink .site-title a {
z-index: 99;
}

.site-header.shrink .widget-area {
padding-top: 0;
}
```

Sorry for all the code but I dont know where it fits in to fix it.

Comment: You can use float:left and then ser your relative positioning offset! Check out the  [mozilla doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [absolute positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning) on the logo container to position it where ever you want it to be. Change the `top, bottom, left, right` parameter to set the offset of the logo container with respect to its parent container.

Try making the below changes and see how absolute positing helps to position the element.

```
.site-header .wrap{
  position:relative;
}

.site-header .title-area{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-35px;
}
//Remove the below styling
.header-image .shrink .site-title > a {
min-height: 60px;
}
```